# deepin-terminal: Failed to execute child process

Tags: shell-script, scripting, terminal, command, deepin

I have written a simple script as below to run deepin-terminal and pass it a simple command but when I execute this script I get error.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

deepin-terminal -m fullscreen -e "cmatrix | lolcat"
```

Error:

```
Failed to execute child process “cmatrix | lolcat” (No such file or 
directory)
```

If I just pass `cmatrix` command it works but it does not work with `cmatrix | lolcat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-e` option for `deepin-terminal`, as for most terminal emulators, takes a simple command.  A pipeline is not a simple command.

The error comes from the terminal trying to execute a command with the literal name `cmatrix | lolcat` (including spaces and pipe symbol).

Instead, use

```
deepin-terminal -m fullscreen -e sh -c "cmatrix | lolcat"
```

This would execute `sh` with an in-line script, which runs your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem but deepin terminal is not running in fullscreen mode anymore. What about that?

Comment: @Miladdarren I'm not familiar with `deepin-terminal` in particular, so I can't really say anything about why it would ignore `-m fullscreen` when combined with `-e`.